# How to fix switch animated button to cover a form input field-sets without breaking the form

Tags: javascript, html, css, forms, css-animations

Trying to create animated div to cover the form input fields, when send button is clicked the cover animation is breaking the form input fields structure.

I have tried to change the position & wrap animated div in different variations in the html.

Rewriting the css animation&position code and this is the closest to expected result I've got. Tried to look for solutions online with no success.

HTML:

```css
* {
  margin: 2px;
  padding: 0;
}


/* -------------------- Contact form style -------------------- */

.formContainer {
  width: 650px;
  padding: 1px;
  margin: 2px;
  border-radius: 100px;
  border: 2px solid black;
}

.fieldsetInput {
  border: none;
  display: inline;
  margin: 0;
}

input {
  border: none;
  border-bottom: 1px solid black;
  margin: 0px 0px 0px 10px;
  min-width: 120px;
}

.submitButton {
  position: relative;
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
  margin: 1px;
  border-radius: 50%;
  border: 0 solid black;
  color: white;
  background-color: black;
}


/* -------------------- Animation -------------------- */

.submitAnimation {
  animation-name: submitAnimation;
  -webkit-animation-name: submitAnimation;
  animation-duration: 1s;
}

@keyframes submitAnimation {
  0% {
    background-color: black;
    left: 0px;
    top: 0px;
  }
  100% {
    background-color: orange;
    left: 598px;
    top: 0px;
  }
}

.curtainAnimation {
  animation-name: curtainAnimation;
  -webkit-animation-name: curtainAnimation;
  animation-duration: 1s;
}

@keyframes curtainAnimation {
  0% {
    background-color: #333;
    width: 0px;
    height: 52px;
    left: 0px;
  }
  100% {
    background-color: #686868;
    width: 598px;
    height: 52px;
    left: 0px;
  }
}
```

```html
<body>

  <form class="formContainer ">

    <div class="curtainAnimation"></div>

    <button class="submitButton submitAnimation" name="submit" type="submit">send</button>

    <fieldset class="fieldsetInput">
      <input placeholder="email" type="email">
      <input placeholder="phone" type="number">
      <input placeholder="name" type="text">
    </fieldset>

  </form>

</body>
```

When clicking the SEND button the expected result:
As the button animation slide to the right new message should cover the form input fields and display new text where the input fields were.

https://jsfiddle.net/danielVep/o3xdafvy/1/

can I fix it using only css? or by using vanilla javascript?

Comment: This would need as much JavaScript as to change classes of the elements but the animations could be done with CSS.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

May be it will work. if it does'nt work, please add a comment.

**css**

```
.formContainer {
    position: relative;
}
.curtainAnimation {
    position: absolute;
    border-radius: 100px;
    top: -1px;
    left: 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

is this what you want to achieve?

`
send

```
<fieldset class="fieldsetInput">
    <input placeholder="email" type="email">
    <input placeholder="phone" type="number">
    <input placeholder="name" type="text">
</fieldset>
```

`

```
`
* {
    margin: 2px;
    padding: 0;
}

/* -------------------- Contact form style -------------------- */
.formContainer {
    width: 650px;
    padding: 1px;
    margin: 1px;
    position: relative;
    border-radius: 100px;
    border: 2px solid black;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.fieldsetInput {
    border: none;
    display: inline;
    margin: 0;
}

input {
    border: none;
    border-bottom: 1px solid black;
    margin: 0px 0px 0px 10px;
    min-width: 120px;
}

.submitButton {
    position: relative;
    width: 50px;
    height: 50px;
    margin: 1px;
    border-radius: 50%;
    border: 0 solid black;
    color: white;
    background-color: black;
}

.formContainer::before {
  content:"";
margin: 1px;
  width:50px;
  height: 52px;
  border-radius: 40px;
  display: inline-block;
  position: absolute;
  animation-name: curtainAnimation;
  animation-duration: 1s;

}


/* -------------------- Animation -------------------- */

.submitAnimation{
    animation-name: submitAnimation;
    -webkit-animation-name: submitAnimation;    

    animation-duration: 1s;
}

@keyframes submitAnimation {
    0% {background-color: black; left: 0px; top: 0px;}
    100% {background-color: orange; left: 598px; top: 0px;}
}

.curtainAnimation {
    animation-name: curtainAnimation;
    -webkit-animation-name: curtainAnimation;
    animation-duration: 1s;
}

@keyframes curtainAnimation {
    0% {background-color: #333; width: 50px; height: 50px; left: 0px;}
    100% {background-color: #686868; width: 648px; height: 50px; left: 0px;}
}
`
```